# How to use "MSHookFunction" in theos?

Tags: iphone, hook, theos

Thank Dustin L. Howett for great theos first.
But I have to hook some C functions, so I must use MSHookFunction.
However it seems that logos doesn't support hooking C functions.
So I write "MSHookFunction(func1,replaced_func1,&original_func1);" in  "%ctor" block in some.xm file.

Compile it.

"error: invalid conversion from ‘objc_class* (*)(NSString*, NSString*)’ to ‘void*’ initializing argument 1 of ‘void MSHookFunction(void*, void*, void**)’"

So what can I do to fix this with theos?

Comment: I don't want to write a new MakeFile for this.Any suggestion that want me to write a new MakeFile is unacceptable.

Comment: Stick in `(void*)` in the appropriate places. Note that this is, strictly speaking, invalid C.